# htaccess redirect to http specific urls and all except on http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect specific url to https and all other on `http` but not working properlym.

`http` to `https` condition is working fine but except https url on `http` section not working

i read multiple answer not multiple `[OR]` condition `!^(login|brandcontroller|...)` that has applied on https to http but not working

```
     #HTTPS:// --> to --> HTTP:// (all url except https urls)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(login|brandcontroller|admin|archives|lightboxs|enquiries|uploaders|brandarchives|content) [NC] 
    RewriteRule . http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    #HTTP:// --> to --> HTTPS:// (specific urls)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(login|brandcontroller|admin|archives|lightboxs|enquiries|uploaders|brandarchives|content) [NC]
    RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

can anyone help to htaccess redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded way to set `!=` `{{REQUEST_URI}}` in htaccess file

## HTTP:// --> to --> HTTPS:// (specific urls)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# force https for all required URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?:login\/signin|forgot|brandcontroller|admin)
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

## HTTPS:// --> to --> HTTP:// (all home)

```
# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(?:login\/signin|forgot|brandcontroller|admin)
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```